# Can i recover data from a Nandroid Backup without the original device?

Tags: backup, nandroid

I'd like to start making scheduled backups to my rooted OnePlus 3T (Oxygen OS 5.0.1) in order to prevent the loss of data from any reason that could occur.

I want to save everything: the entire content of /sdcard and the apps+data. I know doing a Nandroid Backup with TWRP is the best way to make a complete backup of an Android device quickly, but i have a question:

Is it possible to recover data without the original device? If i had a totally new device, would it be possible to extract some specific data from the backup? (For example, read and extract the /sdcard/download directory from the backup, or also extract the data from a given app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would indeed be possible. There are several apps which are able to extract parts of a Nandroid backup, e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or [ROM Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox).

Apart from that, depending on the format used by your Nandroid backup, you can either mount them as loop device (disk images) or unpack them (tarballs) to invesigate/access all contents.

For further details, I'd recommend a look at our [nandroid tag-wiki](/tags/nandroid/info) – and especially follow up to:

- [Restore only part of nandroid image](/q/7851/16575)
- [Extract App Data from Nandroid / CWM Backup](/q/49707/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Nandroid backup is nothing more that just images of partitions of your phone: **/system**, **/boot**, **/data**, **/cache**. It is extractable by any decent archiver that recognizes **img** images, e.g. 7zip.

I done this many times.